# can anybody give a solution of URL Rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a `.htaccess` for url rewriting that looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ms.htm $ $manage_student.php [nc]'
```

The code above gives me an error msg: "Error 500"

I am using apache 5.5.

Can anybody help me with my url rewriting?

Comment: reformat your question so the .htaccess code is in a code block (ether press the 10101 button, or put four spaces before each line)

Comment: we can help with a solution if you actually pose a question: what are you trying to achieve exactly.  What are trying to rewrite from and to? e.g. from /users/joe.htm to /users.php?u=joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a server error because your rule contains errors

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((.*)/)?ms.htm$ manage_student.php [nc]
```

The above rule will rewrite ms.htm and any directory conatining ms.htm (like hello/world/ms.htm) to manage_student.php

Explaining what you want the rewrite to do would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

> [How To Succeed With URLs](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/succeed/)

Answer (score 0):

1. The $ character denotes the end of a regex match. You only need one, and it shouldn't have a space in front of it. That's what's causing the 500 error specifically.
2. The backslash character is an escape character. If you're trying to make sure it's in a directory, you want a forward slash.
3. There shouldn't be an apostrophe at the end of the line (though I'm guessing that was a typo).

With those three things applied, your RewriteRule looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ms.htm$ manage_student.php [NC]
```